# How do I index "or" in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, database

Let's say I have many documents similar to this...

```
{
    name: 'alex',
    city: 'LA',
    about: 'designer',
}

db.people.find({'name':'alex', $or: [{'city':'LA'}, {'about':'designer'}] });
```

If I want to query that, how do I index it? Do I need 2 indexes every time I have an "or"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first word in indexing is always the [official Mongo index documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes).

To answer this question more directly, if you want the query to use indexing on more than just "name", you need an index for all three fields.  While this can be done via three separate indexes, a pair of compound indexes *might* give better results:

```
db.people.ensureIndex({name:1, city:1});
db.people.ensureIndex({name:1, about:1});
```

Before settling on any option, however, I'd utilize Mongo's [explain method](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Explain) to determine what gains each index is giving you over an index-less query (testing on a data set as large as your expected production one).  I'd pay particular attention to the "nscanned", and "nscannedObjects" properties with each combination of index, as well as verify that the desired index is being used using "indexOnly" and "isMultiKey".

As a final note, over-indexing can cause performance issues as well—if they didn't, we wouldn't have to ensure indexes.  Be sure that you need the read speed gains of the indexes more than the write speed losses from those indexes.